# Mock code in another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, mocking, stub

I want to mock Amazon **AWS S3** `getObject`

The code I want to test is the following one: Its in `helper.js`

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.get_data_and_callback = function(callback, extra){
  s3.getObject( {Bucket: SRC_BUCKET, Key: SRC_KEY},
    function (err, data) {
      if (err != null) {
        console.log("Couldn't retrieve object: " + err);
      }else{
        console.log("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");

        callback(data, extra);
      }
  });
}
```

In `test/helper_test.js` **I wrote a test that should mock** the module **AWS**

```
var assert = require('assert');
var mockery = require('mockery');

describe("helper", function() {

  it('loads and returns data from S3 to a callback', function(){
    mockery.enable();

    var fakeaws = {
      S3: function(){
          return {
            getObject: function(params, callback){
            callback(null, "hello")
          }
        }
      }
    }
    mockery.registerSubstitute('aws-sdk', fakeaws);

    function replace_function(err, data){
      console.log(data);
    }

    require('../helper.js').get_data_and_callback(replace_function, null);

  });
});
```

When I require **AWS** in the **Test-File** `test/helper_test.js` like this:

```
aws = require('aws-sdk');
s3 = new aws.S3;
s3.getObject(replace_function)
```

Then my code works, it prints out `hello`.

**BUT** the execution of `require('../helper.js').get_data_and_callback(replace_function, null);`

Doesn't work like expected, **AWS** stays the same its not replaced with my **fakeaws**. What do I wrong? Do you maybe have other solutions to replace **S3** Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have created an [aws-sdk-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock) npm module which mocks out all the AWS SDK services and methods.  https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock

It's really easy to use. Just call AWS.mock with the service, method and a stub function.

```
AWS.mock('S3', 'getObject', function(params, callback) {
    callback(null, 'success');
});
```

Then restore the methods after your tests by calling:

```
AWS.restore('S3', 'getObject');
```

This works for every service and method in the as-sdk.